# Eager loading formula not working with QueryOver

Tags: queryover

I have a formula defined in the mapping as below.

```
public TextMap()
    {
        base.Table("text");
        base.Id(x => x.Id).Column("id").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        base.Map(x => x.Subject).Column("[subject]");
        base.Map(x => x.CountOver).Formula("(count(*) over())").LazyLoad();
    }
```

If I try to eager load count over property during search using below code, nhibernate does not include the column at all in the select statement.

```
var results = Session.QueryOver<Text>().Fetch(x=>x.CountOver).Eager().List();
```

instead if I use below code, it includes the column in the select statement.

```
var results = Session.CreateQuery("from Text fetch all properties").List<Text>();
```

Is there a bug in criteria or queryover for fetching the formula with eager loading or am I missing something in my code?

Comment: I guess this is not possible then with queryover or criteria.